How to have same position and rotation for an object between two coordinate systems.
I have two devices that have different coordinate systems and I want to get the position and rotation of an object from one and display it in the correct position and rotation in the other.
One device is an NDI tracker which uses a right-handed coordinate system and the other is a Magic Leap 2 AR device which uses a left-handed coordinate system. The coordinate system of the NDI tracker is as follows: Up = -x, Right = y, Forward = -z.
The Magic Leap 2 coordinate system is: Up = y, Right = x, Forward = z
I get the position and rotation of the object in the tracker in the form of a homogeneous transformation matrix. I also calculated a transformation matrix between two coordinate systems using the Kabsch algorithm and 4 mutual points.
Using these matrices in the form $T_{ml} = T_{ndi-ml} * T_o$ I get the correct position of the object in magic leap (I set the position of the object from the last column of $t_{ml}$) but the rotation of the object is wrong and so far I can't find a way to fix it.
I'm not sure if my methods are correct or if I need to add other steps, so I would appreciate any help with the formulas or methods.
